# TaskScheduler ExecAction put_WorkingDirectory fails to update its value

Tags: c++, wix, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on a project that needs to install a series of Windows Task Scheduler tasks and for that I created a Wix project and a Custom Action that takes care of all the details. That Custom Action was created using C++ to avoid dependencies on the .NET Framework.

At first I started executing SCHTASKS.EXE from a Wix custom action but, after I managed to create the correct command line to install a task correctly, I realized I couldn't set the Action's Working Directory ('Start in' in the Task Scheduler UI) from the SCHTASKS.EXE command line, because it simply didn't have the option...

I decided then to use COM in C++ (`#import <taskschd.dll> raw_interfaces_only`) to get to the Task Scheduler and tweak the WorkingFolder using the API after installing the Task using SCHTASKS.EXE which was working fine besides that detail.
I managed to get to the task and read its values after installing the task correctly but when I executed `put_WorkingDirectory` method with the current value that **didn't fail actually, but the value wasn't saved into the task**.

Does anyone have a clue why I couldn't get there? This is part of the code I used to get to the ExecAction and set the value successfully. Remember this is within a Wix Custom action so some of the methods calls are Wix's.

This code is actually working and the log shows the correct path I intend to set, but the task doesn't get changed. What am I doing wrong?

```
HRESULT UpdateWorkingDirectory(TaskScheduler::ITaskFolderPtr rootFolder, BSTR taskName, BSTR installFolder)
{
    HRESULT                                     hr          = S_OK;
    TaskScheduler::IRegisteredTaskCollectionPtr taskCollection;
    LONG                                        numTasks = 0;
    TaskScheduler::IRegisteredTaskPtr           thisTask;
    TaskScheduler::ITaskDefinitionPtr           definition;
    TaskScheduler::IActionCollectionPtr         actions;
    TaskScheduler::IActionPtr                   action;
    TaskScheduler::IExecActionPtr               execAction;
    long                                        actionCount;

    hr = rootFolder->GetTasks(NULL, &taskCollection);
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "Cannot get task collection pointer");

    hr = taskCollection->get_Count(&numTasks);
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "Cannot get task collection item count");

    for (LONG taskIdx = 0; taskIdx < numTasks; taskIdx++) {
        TaskScheduler::IRegisteredTaskPtr   registeredTask;
        bstr_t                              taskIdxName;

        hr = taskCollection->get_Item(variant_t(taskIdx + 1), &registeredTask);
        ExitOnFailure(hr, "Cannot get task item %d", taskIdx + 1);

        hr = registeredTask->get_Name(&taskIdxName.GetBSTR());
        ExitOnFailure(hr, "Cannot get task name");
        WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, " registered task name = %s", (LPCSTR)taskIdxName);

        if (strcmp(bstr_t(taskName), taskIdxName) == 0) {
            thisTask = registeredTask;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (thisTask == NULL) {
        hr = E_FAIL;
        ExitOnFailure(hr, "task {%S} not found", taskName);
    }

    hr = thisTask->get_Definition(&definition);
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "error getting task definition for {%S}", taskName);

    hr = definition->get_Actions(&actions);
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "error getting actions for {%S}", taskName);
    WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, " got actions from %S", taskName);

    hr = actions->get_Count(&actionCount);
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "error getting action count for {%S}", taskName);
    WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, " got count = %d from {%S}", actionCount, taskName);

    if (actionCount > 0) {
        bstr_t  actionId;
        bstr_t  arguments;
        bstr_t  path;

        hr = actions->get_Item(1, &action);
        ExitOnFailure(hr, "error getting action[1] for {%S}", taskName);

        hr = action->QueryInterface(&execAction);
        ExitOnFailure(hr, "error getting ExecAction for {%S}", taskName);

        hr = execAction->get_Id(&actionId.GetBSTR());
        ExitOnFailure(hr, "error getting Exec Action id for first exec action of {%S}", taskName);
        WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "  first Exec Action Id is %s", (LPCSTR)actionId);

        hr = execAction->get_Arguments(&arguments.GetBSTR());
        ExitOnFailure(hr, "error getting Exec Action arguments for first exec action of {%S}", taskName);
        WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "  first Exec Action arguments are %s", (LPCSTR)arguments);

        hr = execAction->get_Path(&path.GetBSTR());
        ExitOnFailure(hr, "error getting Exec Action path for first exec action of {%S}", taskName);
        WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "  first Exec Action path is %s", (LPCSTR)path);

        hr = execAction->put_WorkingDirectory(installFolder);
        ExitOnFailure(hr, "error putting working directory for {%S}", taskName);
        WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "  successful put working directory to %S", installFolder);
    }

LExit:
    return hr;
}
```

NOTE: All C++ samples I found used simple interface pointers instead of smart pointers, I preferred smart pointers to avoid taking care of release by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

I had to change my method signature to accommodate username and password

```
HRESULT UpdateWorkingDirectory(TaskScheduler::ITaskFolderPtr rootFolder, BSTR taskName, BSTR installFolder, variant_t username, variant_t password)
```

and add these five lines

```
        thisTask = NULL;

        hr = rootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(taskName, definition, TaskScheduler::_TASK_CREATION::TASK_UPDATE, username, password, TaskScheduler::_TASK_LOGON_TYPE::TASK_LOGON_PASSWORD, variant_t(), &thisTask);
        ExitOnFailure(hr, "error updating task regisration for {%S}", taskName);
        WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "  successful update of task regisration to %S", taskName);
```

after executing put_WorkingDirectory.

This updates the registration of the task definition with the updated value, that was what I wanted to do, and it worked!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is a good example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446854(v=vs.85).aspx

More specifically, it shows that you call ITask::Activate before changing things like the working directory, and that you call IPersistFile to save the changes. I can't see any of these in that posted code sample.  I've not looked at these interfaces for a while, but that might be the issue.

Comment: That's for TaskScheduler 1.0 and I want to set it in the version 2.0. 
The new version has a more complex object hierarchy and it doesn't have a SetWorkingDirectory method at that level, Thank you anyway